# EF Core 2.1 Discriminated Type With Many->Many Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, tph, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have a model that is roughly along the following lines:

```
Expression
ExpressionGroup
  - Expressions (Polymorphic collection via base type that is Either Expression or ExpressionGroup)
  ^ Achieved by means of a base class that is configured with a discriminator column (Type enum)
```

The system I'm working on requires the following:

- Expressions & Groups are uniquely identifiable, and should be shared objects (e.g. Multiple groups can reference the same expression, and the same groups)

I have this configuration set up, with the `HasMany(group => group.Expressions).WithOne()` config because it's the case that a group can have many expression components (base type), but that there's no meaningful navigation property backwards.

This has resulted in a column on each component that tracks which group it belongs to, and when I add a new group referencing an existing expression, the previous group that referenced it loses that reference, and the new one takes over.

[image: Resulting SQL Structure & Values]

I need to be able to have multiple groups reference the same expression (or group/s), but there's no domain reason for going from an expression to a group.

Would the correct way around this just be to introduce a collection nav property against the expression to link to the group(/s) it belongs to?

Or is there some weird Many<->Many change I need to introduce?

---

Below is the entity configuration for these types.

```
void IEntityTypeConfiguration<BA.MetaBlockExpressionBase>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BA.MetaBlockExpressionBase> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("ExpressionComponents");

    builder.HasDiscriminator(e => e.Type)
        .HasValue<BA.MetaBlockExpression>(DTO.Topics.Blocks.MetaBlockExpressionType.Expression)
        .HasValue<BA.MetaBlockExpressionGroup>(DTO.Topics.Blocks.MetaBlockExpressionType.Group);

    builder.Property(e => e.Token)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(e => e.Type)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasIndex(e => e.Token)
        .IsUnique(true);
}

void IEntityTypeConfiguration<BA.MetaBlockExpression>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BA.MetaBlockExpression> builder)
{
    builder.Property(e => e.FacetId)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(e => e.Operation)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(e => e.Values)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasConversion(
            vals => CSVUtilities.ToCsvStringList(vals),
            str => CSVUtilities.FromCsvStringList(str).ToArray());
}

void IEntityTypeConfiguration<BA.MetaBlockExpressionGroup>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BA.MetaBlockExpressionGroup> builder)
{
    builder.Property(g => g.Operator)
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .HasMany(g => g.Expressions)
        .WithOne();
}
```

Of note is that there is another type that needs to reference many of the groups (just groups), but once again, no need for the reverse.

Comment: Once you determine that you need many-to-many relationship, then you can read the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) section of the EF Core to find that *Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.* and an example how to do that.